# Is the function $f(x)=x^{x+1}-(x+1)^{x}$ strictly positive after some point?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

I arrived at the function $f(x)=x^{x+1}-(x+1)^{x}$ and the question that I am interested in is:

> Does there exist $x_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that if $x>x_0$ then $f(x)>0$?

I noticed that when $x=2$ then $f(2)=2^3-3^2<0$ and when $x=3$ then $f(x)=3^4-4^3>0$ and that led me to the conclusion that this function will be negative on the set $[0,c)$ (where $c$ is point such that $f(c)=0$ and that it will be positive on the set $(c, + \infty)$, but I am not sure how to prove it, please try to be as elementary as possible (I am not interested, as is stated in the question, in the interval where the function is negative, just would like to know is it positive after some point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Since
$x^{1/x}$
is decreasing for
$x > e$,
then,
for $x \ge e$,
$(x+1)^{1/(x+1)}
<x^{1/x}
$
or
$(x+1)^x
< x^{x+1}
$.

Note that,
for any $a > 0$,
if $x \ge e$,
$x^{x+a}
> (x+a)^x
$.

Answer (score 4):

This reduces to studying whether

$$x^{x + 1} > (x + 1)^x$$

for all large $x$. Taking a logarithm on each side, this is equivalent to looking at

$$(x + 1) \ln x > x \ln(x + 1)$$

or

$$\frac{\ln x}{x} > \frac{\ln (x + 1)}{x + 1}$$

This holds for all sufficiently large $x$ for several reasons, e.g. by looking at the derivative of $g(t) = \frac{\ln t}{t}$. To be explicit, solving for equality numerically shows that this holds for $x > 2.2932$, approximately.

Comment: That's $e$ exactly, where $\ln(x)=1$.